# Display text in field based on multiple check box selections in Adobe Form

Tags: javascript, adobe

My PDF form has a number of questions on it, some of which are multiselect.

I have the following script:

event.value = (this.getField("Question2b").isBoxChecked(0)==true && this.getField("Question2c").isBoxChecked(0)==true && this.getField("Question2e").isBoxChecked(0)==true && this.getField("Question2f").isBoxChecked(0)==true && this.getField("Question2a").isBoxChecked(0)==false && this.getField("Question2d").isBoxChecked(0)==false)? "Correct": "Incorrect"

but I can't get it to work.

If they select the correct ones (Question2b, 2c,2e and 2f), the script should show an output of "Correct", if they pick anything else, it should show incorrect. I've worked out how to do this for a radio button grouping but can't figure out checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question but I have had issues with isBoxChecked(0) and working with events so I just check the value. It't not the cleanest but it works.

```
this.getField("Question2c").value!='Off' &&
```

rather than

```
this.getField("Question2c").isBoxChecked(0)==true &&
```